# HTML Divs getting pushed out of other divs - Why?

Tags: html

This is hard to explain but I will do my best.

In order to provide the correct footer style for my site, I need to encase my content in a div whose id is body-bot. This div is of course encased in the body div. Now inside that body-bot, I have many other divs.

The problem is that after a bit of JQuery , some divs are getting pushed out of the body-bot when I run it on the browser. ( Checked by using Firebug and page code-source ).

Now my question isn't really about how to fix it, but more on how and why divs can be pushed out of other divs when loaded.

So, what can cause this issue ? Of course if you have some ideas on how to solve the problem, be my guest. I can't really show the exact code because it's enormous...

EDIT : Here is an example of what I mean :

```
<body>
  <div class="body-bot">
      <div class="content">
      </div>
      <div class="banner">
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Becomes :

```
 <body>
  <div class="body-bot">
      <div class="content">
      </div>          
 </div>
      <div class="banner">
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
      </div>
</body>
```

Comment: well with code usually it's easier, can you share some code?

Comment: Ill try giving an exemple EDIT : Done.

Comment: you have JS code that modify this?

Comment: Kind of looks you probably have an extra closing div somewhere in your code that causes body-bot to terminate sooner than expected.

Comment: @BookOfZeus  Normally, no. There are divs inside the body-bot class who are hided,showed.

Comment: @mrtsherman I checked a million times and I really don't believe so... Maybe an echoed </div> though. Argh.

Comment: hidden* shown*, also, could you share the JS code itself, the one that does the changing? or at least try to provide with a http://jsfiddle.net example?

Comment: First things first - have you checked your HTML is valid? Browsers and Firebug start doing weird things like this with invalid HTML.

Comment: So if you disable javascript the problem goes away?

Comment: @mrtsherman Yes, the problem goes away when I remove the jscript. I suspect a </div> closing tag is being generated, but I've yet to find out how and where

Comment: @AndyMadge It does not seem to generate errors, and it is valid when removing the JS

Comment: @BookOfZeus I cannot, unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can think of to insert a closing tag would be to change the innerhtml property on <body> - which doesn't seem likely.  It's more likely that your JS is changing the parent of the inner divs, than that it's somehow inserting a closing tag.

I believe the "parent" property on an element is read-only, so something couldn't be changing the parent that way.

That leaves an appendChild, insertBefore, or appendChild on <body> that has the wrong target - or a call with the right target, but being called on <body> when it should be called on body-bot.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the reason why you'll see this in your console is because you have a trailing closing tag. Have you tried to validate your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

It's not really pushing it out it's closing the body-bot therefore not staying inside the confines of the body-bot. Try using ID's instead of class.  I know ID's tend to hold their contents much easier and better than using a class attribute.

```
  <body>
    <div id="body-bot">
      <div id="content">
      </div>
      <div id="banner">
      </div>
      <div id="footer">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Then of course you'll need to update your css.